# Problem when trying to consume a WebService Soap and carry out a JSON WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, xml, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Good afternoon, I am new to the WSO2 EI (ESB) and I am trying to make an API to consume a SOAP WebService and take it to Json, the question is that I am trying to do it but when I get the answer it indicates an error which does not give me many details.

I am defining my API as follows

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="findSubscriberBalanceBS" context="/APW/Subscriber/FindSubscriberBalanceBS" version="1.0.0" version-type="context">
   <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/executeService" faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="payload" expression="json-eval($)"/>
         <log>
            <property name="payload" expression="$ctx:payload"/>
         </log>
         <property name="country" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.country)"/>
         <property name="lang" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.lang)"/>
         <property name="entity" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.entity)"/>
         <property name="system" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.system)"/>
         <property name="subsystem" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.subsystem)"/>
         <property name="origin" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.origin)"/>
         <property name="userId" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.userId)"/>
         <property name="operation" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.operation)"/>
         <property name="destiny" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.destiny)"/>
         <property name="timestamp" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.timestamp)"/>
         <property name="msgType" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Header.msgType)"/>
         <property name="subscriberId" expression="json-eval($.FindSubscriberBalanceBS.Body.findSubscriberBalanceRequest.subscriberId)"/>
         <log>
            <property name="subscriberId" expression="$ctx:subscriberId"/>
         </log>
         <call-template target="validateRequestTemplate">
            <with-param name="schemaUri" value="conf:/schemas/findSubscriberBalanceBS.json"/>
            <with-param name="responseJsonTitle" value="FindSubscriberBalanceBS"/>
            <with-param name="responseBodyTitle" value="findSubscriberBalanceResponse"/>
            <with-param name="origin" value="{$ctx:destiny}"/>
            <with-param name="destiny" value="{$ctx:origin}"/>
            <with-param name="timestamp" value="{$ctx:timestamp}"/>
         </call-template>
         <log>
            <property name="country" expression="$ctx:country"/>
            <property name="lang" expression="$ctx:lang"/>
            <property name="entity" expression="$ctx:entity"/>
            <property name="system" expression="$ctx:system"/>
            <property name="subsystem" expression="$ctx:subsystem"/>
            <property name="origin" expression="$ctx:origin"/>
            <property name="userId" expression="$ctx:userId"/>
            <property name="operation" expression="$ctx:operation"/>
            <property name="destiny" expression="$ctx:destiny"/>
            <property name="timestamp" expression="$ctx:timestamp"/>
            <property name="msgType" expression="$ctx:msgType"/>
            <property name="subscriberId" expression="$ctx:subscriberId"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.ericsson.com/OCS/OCS_Provision_types/v1">
                  <soapenv:Header/>
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <v1:queryTotalBalanceRequest>
                        <v1:queryCommonInfo/>
                        <v1:subscriberId>
                           <v1:e164Number>$1</v1:e164Number>
                        </v1:subscriberId>
                     </v1:queryTotalBalanceRequest>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:subscriberId"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full"/>
         <header name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value="queryTotalBalance"/>
         <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="text/xml"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint key="altamiraWebServiceEndpoint"/>
         </call>
         <log level="full"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="httpcode return -> " expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

The SOAP WebService I am calling has the following Request and Response:

**REQUEST**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.ericsson.com/OCS/OCS_Provision_types/v1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:queryTotalBalanceRequest>
         <v1:queryCommonInfo/>
         <v1:subscriberId>
            <v1:e164Number>4242441160</v1:e164Number>
         </v1:subscriberId>
      </v1:queryTotalBalanceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

POST http://10.161.79.62:9103/OCS/BalanceManagement-Service_v1 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "queryTotalBalance"
Content-Length: 439
Host: 10.161.79.62:9103
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/12.0.1)
```

**RESPONSE**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 12 Jul 2021 15:29:35 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns3:queryTotalBalanceResponse xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ericsson.com/OCS/OCS_Provision_types/v1" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
         <ns3:balance exponent="-5">11878385641649</ns3:balance>
         <ns3:negativeBalance exponent="-1">0</ns3:negativeBalance>
      </ns3:queryTotalBalanceResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

However, I get the following error in the logs:

```
[2021-07-12 15:12:23,283]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: /APW/Subscriber/FindSubscriberBalanceBS/executeService, MessageID: urn:uuid:d930df60-153a-4350-8f90-dba26d5056bd, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.ericsson.com/OCS/OCS_Provision_types/v1"><soapenv:Body><v1:queryTotalBalanceRequest><v1:queryCommonInfo/><v1:subscriberId><v1:e164Number>4242441160</v1:e164Number></v1:subscriberId></v1:queryTotalBalanceRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2021-07-12 15:12:23,296] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} - Error while building Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space between public and system identifiers
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,55]
```

I do not understand where the error comes from, if I have to tackle the soap output in another way, the truth if this error cannot happen to take it to JSON.

Comment: can you add the complete error stack trace

Comment: I already solved, it was that in calling the endpoint it was not adding that it was of the type soap 1.1